# A doubt about the construction of a linear map $T$ such that $T:\mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R^p$ such that $K \cap \operatorname{ker} T = \{0\}$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, proof-explanation, smooth-manifolds

I'm reading a proof of pre-image theorem in page 15 of [this](https://minterscompactness.files.wordpress.com/2019/01/Differential_Geometry_Part_II_Notes.pdf) lecture note.

**Theorem 1.3** (The Pre-Image Theorem). Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a smooth map of manifolds and let $y \in Y$ be a regular value of $f$. Then if $f^{-1}(y) \neq \emptyset$, then $f^{-1}(y)$ is a submanifold of $X$, with
$$
\operatorname{dim}\left(f^{-1}(y)\right)=\operatorname{dim}(X)-\operatorname{dim}(Y).
$$

---

*Proof.* Let $x \in f^{-1}(y)$. Then since $y$ is a regular value, we know that $\mathrm{d} f: T_{x} X \rightarrow T_{f(x)} Y \equiv T_{y} Y$ is surjective.

Now, the kernel of $\mathrm{d} f_{x}$, which we denote $K$, is a subspace of $T_{x} X$ of dimension (by the rank-nullity theorem) $p:=\operatorname{dim}\left(T_{x} X\right)-\operatorname{dim}\left(\operatorname{Im}\left(\mathrm{d} f_{x}\right)\right)=\operatorname{dim}\left(T_{x} X\right)-\operatorname{dim}\left(T_{y} Y\right)=\operatorname{dim}(X)-\operatorname{dim}(Y)$

Suppose that $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$, and let $T: \mathbb{R}^{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{p}$ be any linear map such that $\operatorname{ker}(T) \cap \operatorname{ker}\left(\mathrm{d} f_{x}\right)=\{0\}^{(\mathrm{ii})}$. Then define the map $F: X \rightarrow Y \times \mathbb{R}^{p}$ by:
$$
F(z):=(f(z), T(z))
$$
Then the derivative of $F$ is given by $\mathrm{d} F_{x}=\left(\mathrm{d} f_{x}, T\right)$, since $\mathrm{d} T=T$ as $T$ is linear. Then by choice of $T$, as $\operatorname{ker}\left(\mathrm{d} f_{x}\right) \cap \operatorname{ker}(T)=\{0\}$, we have $\operatorname{ker}\left(\mathrm{d} F_{x}\right)=\{0\}$, and so $\mathrm{d} F_{x}$ is injective. Then as $\mathrm{d} F_{x}$ is a linear map from $T_{x} X \rightarrow T_{y} Y \times \mathbb{R}^{p}$ and these spaces have the same dimension, we see that $\mathrm{d} F_{x}$ is an isomorphism.

---

There is no doubt that $\operatorname{ker}\left(\mathrm{d} f_{x}\right)$ is a $p$-dimensional vector subspace. The author constructs such $T$ by

> This can be defined as follows. Set $T$ to be zero on $\mathbb{R}^{N} \backslash \operatorname{ker}\left(\mathrm{d} f_{x}\right)$, which is a $N-p$ dimensional subspace. Then set $T$ to be non-zero on $\operatorname{ker}\left(\mathrm{d} f_{x}\right)$, e.g. it could be the identity on this $p$-dimensional subspace.

I suspect that the statement "...$\mathbb{R}^{N} \backslash \operatorname{ker}\left(\mathrm{d} f_{x}\right)$, which is a $N-p$ dimensional subspace..." is not correct. Let $a \in A := \mathbb{R}^{N} \backslash \operatorname{ker}\left(\mathrm{d} f_{x}\right)$ and $b \in B := \operatorname{ker}\left(\mathrm{d} f_{x}\right)$. Surely, $a+b \in \mathbb R^N = A \cup B$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. If $a+b \in A$, then $b = (a+b) -a \in A$ because $A$ is a vector subspace. This contradicts $b \in B$. If $a+b \in B$, then $a = (a+b) -b \in B$ because $B$ is a vector subspace. This contradicts $a \in A$.

Could you elaborate on my confusion?

Comment: Are you reading $\mathbb R^{N}\setminus \ker(df_x)$ as the complement of $\ker (df_x)$? I think it is a quotient space.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I thought the symbol for quotient space is $/$, not $\setminus$. Also, the domain of $T$ is $\mathbb R^N$. How can the "quotient space" $\mathbb{R}^{N} \backslash \operatorname{ker}\left(\mathrm{d} f_{x}\right)$ be a subset of $\mathbb R^N$?

Comment: In usual notations one uses $/. $ but it is clear that they are using $\.$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Could you address my concern in previous comment?

Comment: There is no law that requires Mathematicians to be fully consistent in their notations. You have to interpret symbols based on the conntext. You are just being too fussy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Kavi in comments, but I think I understand your confusion. What is happening is that since $K := \operatorname{ker}(d f_x)$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^N$, there exists a direct sum decomposition $\mathbb{R}^N \cong K \oplus (\mathbb{R}^N / K)$. However, this decomposition is *noncannonical*, which means that it involves an arbitrary choice. If you like, here the arbitrary choice is how to extend a basis for $K$ to a basis of all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Nonetheless, we are allowed to just pick one such decomposition. Then we can define a linear map $T$ from $\mathbb{R}^N$ to $\mathbb{R}^p$ by defining it on each factor $K$ and $\mathbb{R}^N / K$ of the direct sum (however once again, the resulting linear map $T$ will depend on the arbitrary direct sum decomposition we picked, hence the book says "any linear map"). Then we choose to define $T$ on $\mathbb{R}^n / K$ as zero, and something interesting on $K$.

---

Your comments imply that you are not so familiar with the notion of direct sums of vector spaces, so let me give two perspectives on the same construction: one which we build with our "bare hands", and then formulated again using the notion of direct sum to clarify what we are doing.

First, with our bare hands: a linear map $T : \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^p$ is determines and is completely determined by where it sends a basis of $\mathbb{R}^N$. So, if we want to construct such a linear map $T$, we can start by choosing a basis $\{ v_1, \ldots, v_p \}$ of $K = \ker d f_x$. This is a linearly independent subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$, so by adding $N - p$ additional vectors we can extend this to a basis $\{v_1, \ldots, v_p, u_1, \ldots, u_{N - p}\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^N$. Now define $T : \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^p$ by mapping each $v_i$ to the element $e_i$ of the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^p$, and also mapping each $u_j$ to zero. Then we have constructed a map $T$ of the desired form (though note that we have made a lot of choices when we picked all of these basis elements, so again the map $T$ is of course not unique and depends on these choices).

But second, what we are really doing here is the following thing: we have picked an isomorphism $A : K \to \mathbb{R}^p$ and an isomorphism $B : \mathbb{R}^N \to K \oplus (\mathbb{R}^N / K)$, note that both choices are nonunique<sup>[1]</sup>, and then we have just defined $T$ to be the composite
$$
T : \mathbb{R}^N \xrightarrow{B} K \oplus (\mathbb{R}^N / K) \to K \xrightarrow{A} \mathbb{R}^p,
$$
where $K \oplus (\mathbb{R}^N / K) \to K$ is just the projection onto the subspace $K$. This is what our choices of basis vectors above got us: the basis $\{v_i\}$ determines the isomorphism $A$, and the extension to a basis of all of $\mathbb{R}^N$ by the addition of the vectors $\{u_j\}$ determines the isomorphism $B$.

<sub>[1]: Note that technically we need $B$ to respect the inclusion $K \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$, but...</sub>

---

Final remark: note that while your "dimension based" reasoning about the direct sum in comments isn't wrong, it's a bit complex and doesn't at the outset respect the inclusion $K \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$. Instead note that what you have written down is the so-called *external direct sum* (which is fine and is the normal one), but in this situation probably the notion of *internal direct sum* is helpful. You can look this up, but it turns out (and is a good exercise) that if $V_1, V_2 \subseteq V$ are vector subspaces with $V_1 \cap V_2 = \{0\}$ and $\operatorname{span}(V_1 \cup V_2) = V$ then $V$ is isomorphic to the (external) direct sum $V_1 \oplus V_2$. In other words, each element of $V$ is uniquely a sum of an element of $V_1$ and an element of $V_2$ (hence the name "internal"). A consequence of this for example is that a linear map $T : V \to W$ then completely determines and is determined by its restrictions $T \rvert_{V_1} : V_1 \to W$ and $T \rvert_{V_2} : V_2 \to W$ to $V_1$ and $V_2$.

Comment: Could you verify if I understand your answer correctly? Let $V_1, V_2, V$ be $m$-, $n-$, and $(m+n)$-dimensional vector spaces respectively. The vector space $V_1 \oplus V_2$ is defined as follows. The elements of $V_1 \oplus V_2$ are ordered pairs $(v_1, v_2)$ with $v_i \in V_i$ for $i = 1,2$. Addition and scalar multiplication on $V_1 \oplus V_2$ are defined component-wise: $\left(v_{1}, v_{2}\right)+\left(w_{1}, w_{2}\right)=\left(v_{1}+w_{1}, v_{2}+w_{2}\right)$ and $a\left(v_{1}, v_{2}\right)=\left(a v_{1}, a v_{2}\right)$. Then $\dim (V_1 \oplus V_2) = m+n$.[...]

Comment: [...] Moreover, if two vector spaces have the same dimension, then they are isomorphic to each other. This implies $V_1 \oplus V_2 \cong V$.

Comment: @Akira I have added a "bare hands" construction of the map which avoids the notion of direct sum, and then explained the connection afterward. How do you feel about this?

Comment: Thank you so much for your very detailed explanation. Can you explain the "..." in your footnote. It seems to me at the end, we still need to control the behavior of $B$ on its basis so that we can ensure "...$B$ to respect the inclusion $K \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{N}$..". I construct an isomorphism satisfying our requirement in below answer. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an explicit construction of $T$.

---

Let $\{v_1, \ldots, v_p\}$ and $\{u'_1, \ldots, u'_{N-p}\}$ be bases of $K$ and $\mathbb R^N /K$ respectively. Here $u'_j =u_j+K$ for some $u_j \in \mathbb R^N$. Then $\{v_1, \ldots, v_p, u_1, \ldots, u_{N-p}\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^N$. Also, $$\{(v_1, 0), \ldots, (v_p, 0), (0, u'_1), \ldots, (0, u'_{N-p})\}$$ is a basis of $K \oplus (\mathbb R^N /K)$.

Let $f:K \oplus (\mathbb R^N /K) \to \mathbb R^{N}$ be linear that maps $(v_i, 0)$ to $v_i$ and $(0, u'_j)$ to $u_j$. Then $f$ is an isomorphism. Let $g:K \to \mathbb R^p$ be linear that maps $v_i$ to $e_i$ where $\{e_1, \ldots, e_p\}$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb R^p$. Then $g$ is also a isomorphism.

Let $T := g \circ \pi \circ f^{-1}$ where $\pi:K \oplus (\mathbb R^N /K) \to K$ is the canonical projection. Clearly, $T$ is linear. We have \begin{align}
\operatorname{ker} T &= f \circ \pi^{-1} \circ g (0) &&= f \big(\{0\} \times (\mathbb R^N /K) \big ) \\
&= \left \{\sum f \big (\beta_j (0, u'_j)  \big ) \,\middle\vert\, \beta_j \in \mathbb R \right\} &&= \left \{ \sum \beta_j u_j \,\middle\vert\, \beta_j \in \mathbb R \right \}.
\end{align}

It follows that $K \cap\operatorname{ker} T = \{0\}$.